# Replicate number of arguments in function call?

Tags: r

in relation to my other post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838396/faster-combn-expand-grid-with-rcpp

if I have a character vector named `ids` and I want to do:

```
expand.grid(ids,ids)
expand.grid(ids,ids,ids)
expand.grid(ids,ids,ids,ids)
expand.grid(ids,ids,ids,ids,ids)
```

I want to write a function where I can:

```
n_args <- function(var,n, fun)
```

so i can call:

```
result <- n_args(ids,5,expand.grid)
```

to be equivalent to

```
result <- expand.grid(ids,ids,ids,ids,ids)
```

but I'm stuck on:

```
n=5
rep(quote(var),n)

> Error in rep(quote(var), 5) : 
>  attempt to replicate an object of type 'symbol'
```

How do i write such a function or does it exist in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`do.call()` is the way to go as per @nograpes. As the error implies `rep()` has no method for the `symbol` class.

But what if you really want the `n_args(ids,5,expand.grid)` syntax? I thought I'd try to come up with something.

### Alternative solution?

Using `parse()`-type functions I came up with:

```
n_parse <- function(var,n,fun) {
    args_v <- rep(deparse(var),n)
    args_sep <- paste0(args_v,collapse=",")
    fxn_name <- deparse(fun)
    expr <- parse(text=paste0(fxn_name,"(",args_sep,")",collpase=""))
    out <- eval.parent(expr)
    out
}
```

Which gives the something *close* to the desired syntax:

```
result <- n_parse( quote(var), 5, quote(expand.grid) )
```

and a version with string inputs:

```
n_parse_string <- function(var,n,fun) {

    args_v <- rep(var,n)
    args_sep <- paste0(args_v,collapse=",")
    expr <- parse(text=paste0(fun,"(",args_sep,")",collpase=""))
    out <- eval.parent(expr)
    out
}
```

which is used:

```
results <- n_parse_string( "ids", 5, "expand.grid")
```

to give expected output. At the least it's a little practice in non-standard evaluation.

Comment: I think you mean n_parse( and n_parse_string( not nparse/nparse2! but this is what I was looking for thanks! is it possible to get rid of quotes altogether?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `do.call` function. You can pass the function as one of its arguments, and a list of arguments that you want to pass to that function. Here is an example.

```
do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(ids),3))
```